# How can I remove session for specific user for specific ServiceProvider in WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2, identityserver4, wso2-identity-server

There is any webservice providing by WSO2 Identity server, to remove a session for specific user to specific ServiceProvider?
I am using SAMLSSO for many web application and they all are integrating with WSO2 server.
Now let's say scenario is,User is login with 2 application at the same time. I want to logout it from one application.
There is one service provided by logout and it's providing single logout and session will be remove for all application. There is webservice provided by IS or way to achieve logout for one specific application ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is to have the capability of removing a specific participant from the session created in the Identity Server side. I don't see a straight forward way (OOTB) of achieving this.

Closest you can achieve is as below.

1. Make your application perform a `forceAuth`. ForceAuth will request for user credentials despite having the cookies in the browser. (This will prevent the user from experiencing the SSO comfort. Still you can authenticate against the IS)
2. Prevent the application from sending an SLO request to WSO2. Rather, terminate the self(application) session upon logout.
3. When your application really wants to perform an SLO (logout all the applications, not just yours), your application can send an SLO request to the Identity Server.

**Performing a force authentication :**

1. **SAML** - Send `forceAuth=true` as a query paramter in your login request. Or else change the SAML `AuthenricationRequest` payload body to indicate a force authentication as in the [spec(Line 2042)](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf).
2. **OIDC** - Send `prompt=login` as an additional query parameter in the `/authorization` request.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. But this won't solve my problem :(.

Comment: I was thinking to achieve my problem in another way. Do you have any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/q/61143043/8818353  your any insight would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the REST API and SOAP API provided by WSO2 IS. This will remove the session at WSO2 IS but I'm not sure if it will also trigger the SLO to other service providers or not.

Reference:

- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/calling-admin-services/
- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/session-mgt-rest-api/

  1. Trigger a SOAP request getUserProfile from the UserProfileMgtService.wsdl. The default user profile will be 'default' or you can put the customized profile name you used. This will return the details. Grab the user id from this.
  2. Trigger a GET to the API: /{user-id}/sessions with the user-id from step 1 to get the list of all active sessions this user currently have. Go through the list of sessions and find the session ID of the Service Provider you need to clear.
  3. Trigger a DELETE request to API: /{user-id}/sessions/{session-id} with the user id from step 1 & session id from step 2